# Error: Attempted to open an MdDatepicker with no associated input

Tags: angular-material2

I am trying the material 2 datepicker following [the example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)
but I keep getting this error

```
Error: Attempted to open an MdDatepicker with no associated input.
at MdDatepicker.open (material.es5.js:21344)
```

below is my implementation

```
<md-input-container>
                                        <input mdInput 
                                               name="dobdate" 
                                               (selectedChanged)="onSelectDOBDate($event)" 
                                               [(ngModel)]="admissionModel.DOB" 
                                               [mdDatepicker]="picker" 
                                               placeholder="Choose a Date of Birth">
                                        <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="dobpicker"></button>
                                    </md-input-container>
                                    <md-datepicker #dobpicker></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 9):

You are binding with the wrong `md-datepicker` reference. Change `[mdDatepicker]="picker"` to `[mdDatepicker]="dobpicker"` inside the `input` tag.

Comment: Please mark it as 'Accepted' if it resolved your problem :)